# Why is the output of this Verilog simulation always 1?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, boolean-algebra

I am trying to implement following logic:

```
f(A,B,C,D) = ~C~D + ~ABD + ~ACD + A~BD + A~C
```

I have written following Verilog code:

```
module q1 (a,b,c,d,out);    
input a,b,c,d;   
output out;

assign x1 = (~c & ~d);    
assign x2 = (~a & b & d);    
assign x3 = (~a & c & d);    
assign x4 = (a & ~b & d);    
assign x5 = (a & ~c);   
assign out = x1|x2|x3|x4|x5;

endmodule
```

But, when I created testbench to run a simulation, the output is always coming out to be 1 irrespective of the input. Is there any mistake in my code?

These sets of a,b,c,d inputs will give 0 output:

```
0001,0010,0110,1111,1010,1110
```

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs that you would expect to give a zero output?

Comment: or, rather: there's 16 possible inputs.  I'm sure you can spend the 4 minutes needed to calculate all of the possible outputs.

Comment: these will give 0 output: 0001,0010,0110,1111,1010,1110

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is non-reproducable by multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is a bug in your testbench or in your simulator.  I get out=0 for some inputs:

```
module tb;

wire out;
reg a,b,c,d;
q1 q1 (a,b,c,d,out);

initial begin
    $monitor($time, " abcd=%b out=", {a,b,c,d}, out);
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) #5 {a,b,c,d} = i;
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule

module q1 (a,b,c,d,out);    
input a,b,c,d;   
output out;

assign x1 = (~c & ~d);    
assign x2 = (~a & b & d);    
assign x3 = (~a & c & d);    
assign x4 = (a & ~b & d);    
assign x5 = (a & ~c);   
assign out = x1|x2|x3|x4|x5;

endmodule
```

Prints out:

```
 0 abcd=xxxx out=x
 5 abcd=0000 out=1
10 abcd=0001 out=0
15 abcd=0010 out=0
20 abcd=0011 out=1
25 abcd=0100 out=1
30 abcd=0101 out=1
35 abcd=0110 out=0
40 abcd=0111 out=1
45 abcd=1000 out=1
50 abcd=1001 out=1
55 abcd=1010 out=0
60 abcd=1011 out=1
65 abcd=1100 out=1
70 abcd=1101 out=1
75 abcd=1110 out=0
80 abcd=1111 out=0
```

I tried this on 2 different simulators.  You can try it on edaplayground.